# spoiler transitions are strange here

Tags: bug, status-completed, site-design

Spoiler tags are rendering strangely on this site:

> This is a [spoiler](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help#spoilers), introduced with `>!`.

To top it off, it seems that the main site has some transitions that this **meta** site lacks (or which don't work in previews).

Anyway, here's a couple of tidbits about the main site's spoilers from **#whatwg**:

> <SamB> hmm, the spoiler tag in [So obviously, P = NP](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/24401/so-obviously-p-np) acts a bit funny WRT the hyperlink :-)
>   <TabAtkins> SamB: <blockquote class="spoiler"> does a 'color' transition to/from transparent over .5s.  But hyperlinks already have a transition rule for 'color' going over .2s, intended for a more subtle color shift when hovering.  So the blockquote's 'color' rule overrides, but the a's transition wins, and you get the weird extra-fast transition.
>   <TabAtkins> SamB: That's why you shouldn't do silly tricks like a color transition to 'transparent'.  Use 'opacity' on the block element, like God intended, even if it means you need a wrapper element inside the spoiler element.

I don't think you actually need any wrapper elements, though; if I'm understanding `RunBlockGamut` (in https://code.google.com/p/markdownsharp/source/browse/MarkdownSharp/Markdown.cs) correctly, everything inside a blockquote will be inside elements, so we can just use this:

```css
.spoiler>* {
    visibility: hidden; /* Fallback for when opacity doesn't work */
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity .5s ease-in;
}

.spoiler:hover>* {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity .5s ease-in;
}
```

Comment: @Quincunx: yes, that's certainly related; I forgot to link that in my initial post and after that I couldn't decide how best to go about it.  I suppose I should have added a note that "this would also take care of http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/809 "? However, note that my complaint is mostly about transitions (or lack thereof), and I didn't even actually mention that `<code>` is unreadable in spoilers.

Comment: Considering all beta site have the same design (more or less) shouldn't you ask that question on [meta.SE]? I'm guessing the decision of changing that bit of design will have to be made at the level of the network and not just this site.

Comment: @plannapus [The issue was raised at meta SO nearly 2 years ago.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136589/the-monospace-formatting-in-a-spoiler-quote-on-a-beta-site-is-evil) My advice would be simply not to put code blocks inside spoilers.

Comment: See also [this feature request I posted to MSO in January](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/217779/the-css-for-spoilers-is-a-mess-lets-fix-it), which suggests essentially the same solution as yours.

Comment: @plannapus: Hmm, I didn't think of that. Brain hasn't been firing on all cylinders for ages :-(.